# How do I make a CSS & HTML slide show?

Tags: html, css, slideshow, fade

I was wondering how I could make a simple fading, constant CSS and HTML slide show with out any JavaScript or JQuery. I've seen people do it before. But I couldn't find anything on Google that could help me. Nothing beats help from actual web-developers. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Hey man I respect what you're trying to do but feel like you might be re-inventing the wheel a little bit.  Even if you just use CSS3 transitions, I can't think of a way to do this without JavaScript.....Doesn't mean it can't be done, though.

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/ take a look here, - can be done with css3

Comment: There are tons out there. E.g. http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/